# Type 'MyModel' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<MyModel>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9, angular2-observables

I have this TS model:

```
export interface ResearchContentByCompany {
    companyId: number;
    companyOverview: string;
    industryAnalysis: string;
    qualityAssessment: string;
    financials: string;
    valuations: string;
}
```

In the service, this is the api get call I'm making to get the data:

```
public getResearchSectionContentByCompany(companyId) {
        return this.http.get<ResearchContentByCompany>("../api/contenteditor/getresearchcontentbycompany?companyId=" + companyId, {
            headers: this.headers,
        }).pipe(map(data => {
            return data;
        }));
    }
```

In the component I declare this:

```
 researchContentByCompany: Observable<ResearchContentByCompany>;
```

And in ngOnInit method I do this:

```
this.contentEditorService.getResearchSectionContentByCompany(this.DataResult.companyId).subscribe(result => {
                                this.researchContentByCompany = result;
                            });
```

I'm able to get the data as expected from the API but I'm getting this error:

```
    Type 'ResearchContentByCompany' is missing the following properties from type 
'Observable<ResearchContentByCompany>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

I noticed in the get call when I do this.researchContentByCompany[0] = result the error is gone but then the data is missing, since this is not an array but only one object with properties.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: does API return an object or array of objects ?

Comment: One object. I'm able to show the data on the page even with the error but I want to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
researchContentByCompany: Observable<ResearchContentByCompany>;
```

define it as below,

```
researchContentByCompany: ResearchContentByCompany;
```

because the result is type of `ResearchContentByCompany` object only.